# Can't update Fragments in Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigationview

I have a NavigationView where I have tabs like `"Home","Profile","Service"` etc. When I click one of them I want to change the TabLayout and the Input of my ViewPager (Visible Fragments). I change the TabLayout , in the `onNavigationItemSelected` listener, with the method `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(tabViewPager);` which works fine for my TabTitles.

And the change for my Viewpager I try this : `tabViewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter1);` and for example in an other navigation click `tabViewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter2);`.

My ViewPager class looks like this :

```
public class TabViewPagerAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Resources resources;

    public TabViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }}
```

So Im init. my Adapter like this in the beginning :

```
viewPagerAdapter1 = new TabViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter1.addFrag(new Home1Fragment(),"abc");
    viewPagerAdapter1.addFrag(new Home2Fragment(),"def");
```

But nothing changes !The Viewpager is still the same only my Titles of my Tabs are changing. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a good solution so I decided to make fragments for all Navigations. And In these fragments I made seperate Viewpager. Now I have more than one Viewpager.

I think it's not the best solution but it works ^^

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

```
public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: My Problem is that setAdapter() only works in the beginning. After I call this method a second time with a different Adapter ,my viewpager doesn't update the fragments and holds the old Content.

Comment: Can't you achieve the same behaviour with a single adapter? Try adding "removeFragment" or "removeAllFragments" method to the adapter and just reset it before adding new fragments. Don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged` every time you change the underlying data set.

Comment: I tried this now but it doesnt work... I added a method called clearFragList() which is calling .clear() on my lists and after that call I added new Fragments and called notifyDataSetChanged(). Not working :(  other ideas ?